# Importing multiple .csv files into R with differents names

Tags: r, csv, import, filenames

I have one work directory with 37 Locations.csv and 37 Behavior.csv

See below that has some files having the same number as `111868-Behavior.csv` and `111868-Behavior 2.csv`, so also with Locations.csv

```
#here some of the csv in the work directory

dir()
  [1] "111868-Behavior 2.csv"            "111868-Behavior.csv"             
  [3] "111868-Locations 2.csv"           "111868-Locations.csv"            
  [5] "111869-Behavior.csv"              "111869-Locations.csv"            
  [7] "111870-Behavior 2.csv"            "111870-Behavior.csv"             
  [9] "111870-Locations 2.csv"           "111870-Locations.csv"            
 [11] "112696-Behavior 2.csv"            "112696-Behavior.csv"             
 [13] "112696-Locations 2.csv"           "112696-Locations.csv"
```

I can't change the name of files.

I want to import all the 36 Locations and 36 Behaviors, but when I tried this

```
#Create list of all behaviors
bhv <- list.files(pattern="*-Behavior.csv")
bhv2 <- list.files(pattern="*-Behavior 2.csv")

#Throw them altogether
bhv_csv = ldply(bhv, read_csv)
bhv_csv2 = ldply(bhv2, read_csv)

#Join bhv_csv and bhv_csv2
b<-rbind(bhv_csv,bhv_csv2)

#Create list of all locations
loc <- list.files(pattern="*-Locations.csv")
loc2 <- list.files(pattern="*-Locations 2.csv")

#Throw them altogether
loc_csv = ldply(loc, read_csv)
loc_csv2 = ldply(loc2, read_csv)

#Join loc_csv and loc_csv2
l<-rbind(loc_csv,loc_csv2)
```

Shows me only 28, not 36 like I spected

```
length(unique(b$Ptt))
[1] 28

length(unique(l$Ptt))
[1] 28
```

This number 28, is about all `Behaviors.csv` and `Locations.csv` without `Behaviors 2.csv` and `Locations 2.csv` (those with number "2" are 8 in total each one)

I want to import all the files Behaviors and all the Locations in a way that shows the 36 Behaviors and Locations. How can I do that?

Comment: why do you need two separate `list.files` for `Behavior` ? Can you do `list.files(pattern="Behavior")` ? It should cover both the patterns and then same for `Locations` ?

Comment: I made this now, on list created shows 36, but when I run ```length(unique(b$Ptt))```shows me only 28 yet..

Comment: I don't know what `Ptt` column has but since you want two different dataframes for "Behavior" and "Pattern". Try doing, `b <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern="Behavior", full.names = TRUE),fread))`  and make sure you have `data.table` loaded because `fread` and `rbindlist` are from `data.table`.

Comment: The column Ptt, shows the numbers of each Behaviors or Locations, like ```111868``` or ```111869``` (every number is one animal ```111868-Behavior 2.csv``` and ```111868-Behavior.csv``` are 2 animals, for example), are 36 numbers but shows only 26. I tried this code you told me, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map` to simplify some of your code:

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("readr")

# Create two small csv files
write_lines("a,b\n1,2\n3,4", "file1.csv")
write_lines("a,c\n5,6\n7,8", "file2.csv")

list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>%
  # `map` will cycle through the files and read each one
  map(read_csv) %>%
  # and then we can bind them all together
  bind_rows()
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   a = col_double(),
#>   b = col_double()
#> )
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   a = col_double(),
#>   c = col_double()
#> )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2    NA
#> 2     3     4    NA
#> 3     5    NA     6
#> 4     7    NA     8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>